# Is there any way to find phone number from string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters

I am stack to finding a filter or any way to find a phone number from string. Actually I get a response in string and there is a phone number too and client want to make link because of smart-phone when user tab on it. it's goes to call directory.

here is client request to do with response.
"Low priority but could we make it so that the phone number is a hyper link so the user can press and it goes to make call.

I.e.
0035312998080
Or
+35312998080"

here is a test response.

```
Unable to process this booking online it is too close to the party date. To book please phone Fun Fitness - Play Centre on 353 - 1 - 2998080
```

Comment: seems like a case for regex.  Even though you may be using angular in your project, I'm not sure that the angular tags are appropriate here, because it is probably something that is more generic JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to find it? It's right there...

To make it callable:

```
<a href="tel:+15555551212">555-555-1212</a>
```

<sub>Stolen from [How to create hyperlink to call phone number on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13662175/2407212)</sub>